# Angularjs function with parameter

Tags: angularjs, function, parameters

I have the following code:

```
$scope.someVar = function(parameter){
if ($scope.parameter[this.$index].toCheck == 'false') {
  $scope.anotherVar= '.'
} else {
  $scope.anotherVar = ', to check with you if it has worked.'
}
};
```

When I then call in HTML:

```
<a href="#" ng-repeat="test in tests" ng-click="template(emails)">Link</a>
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at ChildScope.$scope.someVar (mainController.js:80)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: where does `$scope.parameter` comes from? do you want it to be `parameter` instead? Because it's not an array, so you can't take an index (_property_) of it with `[this.index]`. Is `this.index` even an number, or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly states that `$scope.parameter[$index]` is undefined, and you're trying to access `toCheck` property from it. 
It seems like you you are expecting `parameters` variable in `$scope`. Rather you should refer to function parameter `parameter`

```
if ($scope.parameter[this.$index].toCheck == 'false') {
```

should be

```
if (parameter[this.$index].toCheck == 'false') {
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much @PankajParkar :)